# Does Quickbooks support backups using Volume Shadow Copy?

Tags: backup, quickbooks

Does Quickbooks support backups using Volume Shadow Copy?

Comment: Do you mean Volume Shadow Copy?

Comment: Yes, Volume Shadow Copy.  Thanks.

Comment: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) @spoulson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Volume Shadow Copy will copy/clone/backup the data files, but the QuickBooks application itself does not support the VSS/shadow copy service. Thus, any opened QuickBooks files will be marked in a "crash consistent" state, which means that I/O writes could have not completed and the file could be corrupted.

Your best bet for QuickBooks backups is to use the backup scheduler that's built into QuickBooks, or make sure that everyone closes out of QuickBooks at the end of the day, so you can do backups overnight.

Comment: Thanks Keith! Do you know if Quickbooks has an API that will initiate a dump of the database so we can safely back it up?

Comment: I don't believe so. If it does, I've never heard of it. Is there a reason you can't use the backup scheduler that's built into QuickBooks?

Comment: Keith, that would be a good idea.  Have you heard of a place where I could figure out if there was API's etc... to do so? 

Thanks!

Comment: I would ask on the Intuit Developer Forums: https://idnforums.intuit.com/

I think you're just going to find out that there isn't an API for that though...

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Will do.  Do you know if there is a way to SAFELY close down the application and then restart it so I could simply script the backup software to backup the db then simply reopen it up after the backup? 

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know. Again, I'd recommend using the backup program built in to QuickBooks, so that you don't need to worry about all of these problems...

Comment: I continue to be appalled at the poor quality that continues to emit from the doors of Intuit. Granted this thread is five years old by now, but that actually makes the situation worse—very little has improved since then (while prices have increased substantially). Force manual backups on users? Terrible, absolutely terrible.

Answer (score 0):

there is no api for database dumping, there are third party extensions to provide odbc access but it export the tables but not the file itself

you can not automatically close quickbooks because it use to show dialog boxes regarding updates, if you are sure to close, telling you not to forget backup.. etc, plus any automation solution need to be on any user (believe me is easy for them to forget to close quickbooks)

to make it worst the internal backup can not be used if you don't shutdown everybody and run in single user mode and then you have to switch back to multi user mode

even intuit online backup does not work if the company file is open

just fight with everybody to close before they leave the office and setup any automatic backup system in place, I recommend Cobian Backup, syncplicity sugarsync and others, as far as you use them only to keep a clone of your quickbooks file not for simultaneous use

Comment: forgot to mention you need to use the internal backup tool time to time it does a maintenance to the file necessary for performance reasons and the process find errors in the quickbooks file and let you rebuild the data if necessary, I have automatic daily backups in place (one online, one a backup software to an external drive), and manual using quickbooks backup tool and microsoft sync toy to copy all the file and all the attachments to a second computer and a portable hardrive that goes out of the office